# Detecting if CFX Tag is registered or not

Tags: coldfusion

I have developed some custom tags for my application, but they may or may not be deployed at client site. If not, I want to handle it gracefully (by using alternative methods). How can I do this?

Using cftry/cfcatch to detect, but there must be some more elegant way of doing it. Using Coldfusion 10.

```
<!--- Missing custom tag --->
<cftry>
     <cf_blah>
<cfcatch type="Any">
     The specified custom tag does not exist!
     <!--- additional processing here --->
</cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Administrator API to manage CFX tags. Here is a way to get started.

```
createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.administrator").login({password}, {username});
myObj = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.extensions");
```

Where `{username}` is the name of the name of the user used to login to ColdFusion administrator and `{password}` is the password for that user.

You can then dump out myObj to see the methods available.

```
writeDump( myObj );
```

Using this, you should be able to check for the existence of the CFX tag and, if you desire, register it.

More information can be had [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fcf.html).

Comment: But I am on Shared Host

Comment: Using shared hosting is a piece of information that would have been important to note in the question. As such, I am pretty sure `cftry` is all you can do. On a side note, why are you running the 'client site' on shared hosting?